# I've been making conway's game of life in python, why doesn't it work?

Tags: python, pygame, conways-game-of-life

So there must be something wrong with the code which detects wether it should be alive or not in Cell.update(), but the glider i hardcoded in is not working as intended. The first and second generations work as intended, but on the third it dies out. Anyone know what the problem is? I know the code is a bit messy, but I'm quite new to python so it is expected. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
import pygame

"""
rules:

1. Any live cell with two or three live neighbours survives.
2. Any dead cell with three live neighbours becomes a live cell.
3. All other live cells die in the next generation. Similarly, all other dead cells stay dead.

number cells on screen = 32x18
cell size = 30x30
"""

# variables
WIDTH = 960
HEIGHT = 540
TITLE = "Conway's Game Of Life"

GRID_COLOUR = (200, 200, 200)
BG_COLOUR = (255, 255, 255)

grid = [[False] * 32] * 18
cells = []

live_queue = []
die_queue = []

# window
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), vsync=1)
pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)


# classes
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, x, y, alive, index_x, index_y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.alive = alive
        self.indexX = index_x
        self.indexY = index_y

    def die(self):
        self.alive = False

    def live(self):
        self.alive = True

    def get_index(self):
        return self.indexX, self.indexY

    def update(self):
        grid_temp = grid[self.indexY]
        grid_temp.pop(self.indexY)
        grid_temp.insert(self.indexY, self.alive)

        grid.pop(self.indexY)
        grid.insert(self.indexX, grid_temp)

        adjacent_alive = 0
        for i in cells:
            if i.x == self.x - 30 and i.y == self.y and i.alive:
                adjacent_alive += 1
            elif i.x == self.x + 30 and i.y == self.y and i.alive:
                adjacent_alive += 1
            elif i.x == self.x and i.y == self.y - 30 and i.alive:
                adjacent_alive += 1
            elif i.x == self.x and i.y == self.y + 30 and i.alive:
                adjacent_alive += 1
            elif i.x == self.x - 30 and i.y == self.y - 30 and i.alive:
                adjacent_alive += 1
            elif i.x == self.x - 30 and i.y == self.y + 30 and i.alive:
                adjacent_alive += 1
            elif i.x == self.x + 30 and i.y == self.y - 30 and i.alive:
                adjacent_alive += 1
            elif i.x == self.x + 30 and i.y == self.y + 30 and i.alive:
                adjacent_alive += 1

        if self.alive:
            if adjacent_alive < 2:
                return False
            elif adjacent_alive > 3:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        if not self.alive:
            if adjacent_alive == 3:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def render(self):
        if self.alive:
            pygame.draw.rect(wn, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, 30, 30))


# functions
def render_grid():
    for y in range(0, HEIGHT, 30):
        pygame.draw.line(wn, GRID_COLOUR, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

    for x in range(0, WIDTH, 30):
        pygame.draw.line(wn, GRID_COLOUR, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT))


def parse_to_x_y(x, y):
    return x * 30, y * 30


def parse_to_index(x, y):
    return int(x / 30), int(y / 30)


indexX = 0
indexY = 0
x_pos = 0
y_pos = 0
for y_ in range(18):
    for x_ in range(32):
        cells.append(Cell(x_pos, y_pos, False, indexX, indexY))
        indexX += 1
        x_pos += 30
    y_pos += 30
    x_pos = 0
    indexY += 1
cells[2].live()
cells[35].live()
cells[65].live()
cells[66].live()
cells[67].live()

# main loop
fps = 1
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    # start_time = time.time()

    wn.fill(BG_COLOUR)

    for item in cells:
        item.render()
    render_grid()

    # events loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    for item in cells:
        if item.update():
            live_queue.append(item)
        else:
            die_queue.append(item)
    for i in live_queue:
        i.live()
    for i in die_queue:
        i.die()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
    # end_time = time.time()
    # print(round(1 / (end_time - start_time)), "fps")
```

Comment: Thank you for the upvote and accept on my answer.  I made a few edits after you accepted it so I hope you saw them. If you get your simulation to work, let me know with a comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with commenter Rabbid76, in that **you need to update the entire grid at once, not cell by cell.** This is usually done by using **two separate grids**, an "previous state" grid and a "new state grid". Loop through each position in the "new state" grid and calculate its number of live neighbors using the "previous state" grid. After the entire "new state" grid is calculated, you can copy to "new state" grid to the "old state" grid.

Another fatal flaw in your algorithm is `grid = [[False] * 32] * 18`. **This will not work as expected in Python**. With this code, each row is a reference to the same array. For instance, the expression `grid[0] is grid[1]` will evaluate to `True`. If you set a certain cell in the grid to true, the entire column will be set to true. You can fix this via the code:

```
grid=[]
for r in range(18):
    row=[]
    for c in range(32):
        row.append(False)
    grid.append(row)
```

Though it isn't directly related to the bug, I suggest a bit of a redesign of your algorithm. It is not really needed to encapsulate each cell in a class; doing so creates a redundancy between the grid and list of cells. This also leads you to identify cells by their pixel position (hence the `i.x == self.x - 30` clause), which can easily lead to bugs. I suggest checking adjacent indices in the grid variable instead. Try looking into https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/conways-game-life-python-implementation/ for some inspiration.

Comment: *"you need to update the entire grid at once, not cell by cell"*: this is actually what the code is already doing: it does so via a queue system. I don't understand why this is even put in bold -- it is not the problem.

Comment: @trincot Hmm... You are right, since the `update` function returns a value without modifying `self.alive`, the queue system handles the previous state/next state issue properly. Nonetheless, it seems like an overly complicated way to do it. The name `update` also implies a change to `self.alive` which is not present, leading to confusing code. I suggest changing `update()` to `should_live()`,  or `should_set()`, since this function determines if the cell should be alive in the next generation.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you don't reset your queues in the main loop.

So add this before adding to the queues:

```
live_queue = []   # <----
die_queue = []    # <----
for item in cells:
    if item.update():
        live_queue.append(item)
    else:
        die_queue.append(item)
```

#### Some other remarks

You never use `grid` or `grid_temp` in a useful way. Even the operations you make on them are strange. Any way, you can just remove all references to them.

You never use the `indexX` or `indexY` attributes, nor the method around it, nor the corresponding arguments to the constructor. All that can go.

You should avoid scanning **all** the cells just to find the (up to) 8 neighbors of one cell: this has a bad impact on performance.

Comment: Why have you marked the other answer as accepted? It does not solve the issue...

Comment: it did for me for whatever reason

Comment: Then I really don't understand, because the other answer does not address the issue you had with the queues. The only problem you really had were 2 missing lines.

Comment: ...and a few variables that had no use.